# behavior of filters in outer join

Tags: sql

I understand filters in JOIN clause and in WHERE clause is different when using outer join. Let's say I have these 2 tables.

```
table1
id | value
---+------
 1 |    11
 2 |    12

table2
id | value
---+------
 1 |   101
```

Now if I query for

```
select a.id as id1, a.value as value1, b.value as value2
from table1 as a
left join table2 on a.id=b.id and a.value=11
```

The result is this, an extra row with value1=12

```
id1 | value1 | value2
----+--------+--------
 1  |     11 |     101
 2  |     12 |    NULL
```

However, if I put the filter in where clause, it gives me what I want. The question is why it behaves like this?

Comment: The predicate in the on clause determines whether or not a row from the left side joins with one on the right. The predicate in the where clause runs after all the joined rows have been matched up and outer rows preserved on the result of the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second condition used on your left join example limits which rows will be considered for joining.

```
select f1.id as id1, t1.value as value1, t2.value as value2
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id AND T2.VALUE=11

t1
id | value
---+------
 1 |    11 ONLY join on this row because t1.value=11
 2 |    12

t2
id | value
---+------
 1 |   101 this has t1.id=t2.id, so it does get joined

which would produce this final result:

id1 | value1 | value 2
----+--------+--------
 1  |     11 |     101
 2  |     12 |    NULL
```

Moving the predicate `T2.VALUE=11` to the where clause has a different series of events, as follows:

```
select f1.id as id1, t1.value as value1, t2.value as value2
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
WHERE T2.VALUE=11

t1
id | value
---+------
 1 |    11 this row does meet t1.id=t2.id, so it gets joined
 2 |    12 this row does NOT meet t1.id=t2.id, FAILS to join

t2
id | value
---+------
 1 |   101 this row does meet t1.id=t2.id, so it gets joined

which would produce this INTERIM result:

id1 | value1 | value 2
----+--------+--------
 1  |     11 |     101
 2  |     12 |    NULL

NOW the where clause is considered

id1 | value1 | value 2
----+--------+--------
 1  |     11 |     101 T2.VALUE does equal 11 so this row will be returned
 2  |     12 |    NULL T2.VALUE does NOT = 11 so this row is NOT returned

Thus the final result is:

id1 | value1 | value 2
----+--------+--------
 1  |     11 |     101
```